# Independent map reduce jobs to executed one after other

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Is that possible to execute Independent map reduce jobs (not in chaining where the output of reducer

1. Becomes input of mapper.
2. That can be executed one after the other.

Comment: In which environment you are executing? In Amazon EMR configuration you have some option to add jobs.

Comment: Hi @VanajaJayaraman  I am running in apache hadoop 2.4.1

Comment: I asked the environment. That means, whether local linux machine or cloud storage?

Comment: Linux machine with 5 node cluster, Not cloud Storage

Comment: How do you execute your map/reduce jobs?

Comment: If they are independent jobs then you can execute them in seperate scripts. Or if you want to execute one after the other, then what do you mean by "not in chaining"?

Comment: Yes I know that we can execute in separate scripts since there is no output dependency. I will clarify you a bit more about my input.  I have two inputs one is distributed cache which gives me input to run the the map reduce against other input data (second input with loads of data)._ I want to give multiple inputs in the distributed cache so that I can run against large data_.

Comment: Sorry I am not clear. What do you specify as input File argument? Your distributed cache or loads of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your driver code call two methods runfirstjob,runsecondjob.just like this.this is just a hint, do modification according to your need

```
public class ExerciseDriver {


static Configuration conf;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExerciseDriver ED = new ExerciseDriver();
    conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    if(args.length < 4) {
        System.out.println("Too few arguments. Arguments should be:  <hdfs input folder> <hdfs output folder> <N configurable Integer Value>");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String pathin1stmr = args[0];
    String pathout1stmr = args[1];
    String pathin2ndmr = args[2];
    String pathout2ndmr = args[3];

    ED.runFirstJob(pathin1stmr, pathout1stmr);

    ED.runSecondJob(pathin2ndmr, pathout2ndmr);

}

public int runFirstJob(String pathin, String pathout)  

 throws Exception {

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(ExerciseDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ExerciseMapper1.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(ExerciseCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ExerciseReducer1.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(ParagrapghInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(pathin));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(pathout));

   job.submit();  

   job.getMaxMapAttempts();

   /*
   JobContextImpl jc = new JobContextImpl();
   TaskReport[] maps = jobclient.getMapTaskReports(job.getJobID());

    */

    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return success ? 0 : -1;

}

  public int runSecondJob(String pathin, String pathout) throws Exception { 
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(ExerciseDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ExerciseMapper2.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ExerciseReducer2.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(pathin));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(pathout));
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return success ? 0 : -1;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute one after another, then you can chain you jobs as per the below link:

http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/chaining-jobs-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html

Comment: In chaining you know that output of reducer becomes the input of the second mapper. I don't want that I want second mapper to execute independently with separate input

Comment: Try by removing the line job.waitForCompletion(true); from the code given in the above referred link.

Comment: Hi above code from @sravan makes the program to run two independent map reduce jobs.Any how thanks for the discussion@Vanaja Jayaraman

Comment: I think the link which I stated is also doing the same... If can please check it...

Answer (score 0):

```
You can go with Parallel job running. Sample code is given below

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path Job1InputDir = new Path(args[0]);
Path Job2InputDir = new Path(args[1]);
Path Job1OutputDir = new Path(args[2]);
Path Job2OutputDir = new Path(args[3]);
Job Job1= submitJob(conf, Job1InputDir , Job1OutputDir );
Job Job2= submitJob(conf, Job2InputDir , Job2OutputDir );
// While both jobs are not finished, sleep
while (!Job1.isComplete() || !Job2.isComplete()) {
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
if (Job1.isSuccessful()) {
System.out.println(" job1 completed successfully!");
} else {
System.out.println(" job1 failed!");
}
if (Job2.isSuccessful()) {
System.out.println("Job2 completed successfully!");
} else {
System.out.println("Job2 failed!");
}
System.exit(Job1.isSuccessful() &&
Job2.isSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
}
```